# How to post value of cke editor in codeigniter using ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter, ckeditor, fckeditor

I am using  ckeditor in codeigniter. here is url - [ckeditor](http://tutsnare.com/integrate-ckeditor-in-codeigniter/)

I want to post value of ckeditor using Ajax jquery.
Give me suggestion how to send value using jquery.
Her is my code Of ckeditor in codeignitor view page.

```
echo $this->ckeditor->editor("info","");
```

I want to send value by ajax.

Comment: have you read the CDEditor docs? http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_savedata

Comment: Where is the javascript code you tried (the ajax part)?